# Why is AJAX data not received by PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following extremely simple PHP tester:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">send request</button>

<script>
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxTest.php",
            data: {userresponse: "hi"},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data)
                analyse()
            }
        })
    })

    var analyse = function () {
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["userresponse"])){
                $variable = $_POST["userresponse"];
                switch($variable){
                    case "hi":
                        echo 'alert("' . $variable . '")';
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo 'alert("LOGIC")';
                }
            }
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

What's supposed to happen is that when I click the button, it sends the data `userresponse: "hi"` to the server, and then PHP receives it and alerts the value (i.e. "hi")

However, despite the fact that the file paths are correct, the AJAX send is OK in XHR, the PHP does not receive the value of the data, and the `alert(data)` returns the entire HTML document.

What is going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: write php code inside ajaxTest.php

Comment: The php _is_ inside ajaxTest.php

Comment: The default type of an HTML `<button>` element is `submit`, which will (despite your AJAX effort) refresh the page. Change to `<button type="button"...>`

Comment: then why have you created analyse function?

Comment: You should not mix javascript and php unless they got the right headers to handle it. Javascript and PHP are two different languagues.

Comment: I changed it to type = "button" but there's no change in the results.

Comment: As some commenters already told you: You have to understand that `data` in your ajax success callback contains all the output of `ajaxTest.php` which includes the full `<HTML>` part and all the Javascript source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `analyze()` and put your php code in external file called ajaxTest.php, your code works perfect just remove your php code fron analyze and request for external this is bad practice having both in same file(header problems).

Proof:
[image]

Comment: How do I allow it to do the same thing of returning a javascript alert instead of returning that?